# SQL MAX join query returns multiple rows

Tags: postgresql, join, max

I wrote a small select query, which is a part of larger one that I use to retrieve items with their additional properties from few tables in PostgreSQL DB.

```
SELECT 
  isni.inventory_id_inventory,
  max(isni.issue_note_id_issue_notes) AS latest_issue_note,
  isn.direction
FROM issue_note_items isni
JOIN issue_notes isn ON isni.issue_note_id_issue_notes = isn.id
GROUP BY isni.inventory_id_inventory, isn.direction
```

All I need is to get one record for each of table with `inventory_id_inventory` key, with highest `issue_note_id_issue_notes` value. Or other words, i would like to find **one, last** issue note with it's direction for each of the distinct inventory id.

What I get is one or two rows - if there are two diffrent directions (there are two small int values possible in this column). Seems easy, should be fixed using left join, but it does'nt work as expected probably becouse of `GROUP BY` clause. What should I do to make it work as expected?

Tables and example data:
`issue_notes`

```
ID  direction
1   1
2   2
3   2
4   1
5   2
6   1
```

`issue_note_items`

```
ID  inventory_id_inventory  issue_note_id_issue_notes
1   12                      1
2   123                     1
3   12                      2
4   12                      4
5   35                      4
6   123                     5
7   35                      6
```

Expected output:

```
ID  inventory_id_inventory  issue_note_id_issue_notes  direction
4   12                      4                          1
6   123                     5                          2
7   35                      6                          1
```

Thank You very much for any help

Comment: Please include sample data, table definitions and expected output in your question

Comment: If you want only one row, all grouped columns need to have exact one value. in your case, you have 2 values for `isn.direction`. Therefor, you get 2 rows as id1 and direction1 is a different value than id1 and direction2. If you want to return exactly one row per `...id_inventory` you'd have to group only by this and select `max(isn.direction)`

Comment: @MKhalidJunaid Sorry for late reply, I've hadsome other projects on my desk to finish. I've put some additional info, I hope it helps any way to find a solution.

Comment: @Chrᴉz I understand your suggestion. Now I can see where the problem exists. But I still cannot solve it. I cannot put max(isn.direction) as I want to retrieve data what direction was for last issue note of the inventory. Using MAX i get only those with '2'.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Rows in a relational database have no order. There's no "last" entry unless something specifies an order.

In this case it appears the order is by ascending `inventory_id_inventory` for each `inventory_id_inventory`. Given that order, one can use the `ROW_NUMBER()` ranking function to calculate a rank for each result of the join , eg :

```
SELECT 
  isni.id,
  isni.inventory_id_inventory,
  isni.issue_note_id_issue_notes,
  isn.direction,
  ROW_NUMBER() OVER(partition by inventory_id_inventory 
                    order by issue_note_id_issue_notes desc) as rn
FROM issue_note_items isni
JOIN issue_notes isn ON isni.issue_note_id_issue_notes = isn.issue_note_id
```

`partition by inventory_id_inventory` means we want a separate ranking per partition by inventory_id_inventory.  `order by issue_note_id_issue_notes desc` will return 1 for the *largest* ID, making it easier to filter for the "latest" entry.

It's not possible to refer to the `rn` function in the `where` clause. This can be fixed by using a CTE :

```
with notes as (
    SELECT 
      isni.id,
      isni.inventory_id_inventory,
      isni.issue_note_id_issue_notes,
      isn.direction,
      ROW_NUMBER() OVER( partition by inventory_id_inventory 
                         order by issue_note_id_issue_notes desc) as rn
    FROM issue_note_items isni
    JOIN issue_notes isn ON isni.issue_note_id_issue_notes = isn.issue_note_id      
)
select * 
from notes
where rn=1
order by issue_note_id_issue_notes
```

Using the following data :

```
create table issue_notes (issue_note_id int,direction int);
create table issue_note_items (id int, inventory_id_inventory  int,issue_note_id_issue_notes int);

insert into issue_notes
values
(1,1),
(2,2),
(3,2),
(4,1),
(5,2),
(6,1);

insert into issue_note_items 
values
(1,12 ,1),
(2,123,1),
(3,12 ,2),
(4,12 ,4),
(5,35 ,4),
(6,123,5),
(7,35 ,6);
```

The result will be :

```
|id |inventory_id_inventory |issue_note_id_issue_notes  |direction  |rn
|4  |12                     |4                          |1          |1
|6  |123                    |5                          |2          |1
|7  |35                     |6                          |1          |1
```

SQL Fiddle [here](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!17/47e98/1)

Comment: Looks like you hit the point. Thank you. This works as expected.

Answer (score 0):

I wrote something in my project, it may look like this

```
SELECT 
  isni.inventory_id_inventory,
  isni.issue_note_id_issue_notes AS latest_issue_note,
  isn.direction
FROM issue_notes isn 
left join lateral (
  select 
    isni.inventory_id_inventory,
    isni.issue_note_id_issue_notes
  from issue_note_items isni
  where isni.issue_note_id_issue_notes = isn.issue_note_id
  order by isni.issue_note_id_issue_notes desc
  limit 1      
) as isni on true
```

Comment: Sorry for late reply. This doesn't work form me, as it brings me even more duplicated records. Plese see main post, as I edited it to provide a little bit more details. Maybe it helps.

Comment: @Smok please add output data that you expect from query - it'll help

Comment: I've edited my main post. If I didn't made any mistakes (in manual table creation)  it should suit my needs. Thank you from the top for your kind help.